# remove leaf nodes from data

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, hierarchy

I'm making a circle packing and there are too many nodes in the graphic, so I'm trying to reduce the amount of nodes by removing the leaf nodes.

The data I get from the api is a json object that looks like this:

```
{
    Children: [], 
    Label: "some str", 
    Value: some int, 
    Properties:[]
}
```

I am trying to make a function that loops through the data and if the object has no children it gets removed. Here is what I'm on

```
function removeLeaves(data){
let keys = Object.entries(data);
for(let [name,obj] of keys){
    if(name == "Children"){
        if((<Array<any>>obj).length > 0){
            for(let child of (<Array<any>>obj)){

                removeLeaves(child);
            }
        }
        else{
            data = {}; //delete object
        }
    }

  }
}
```

but since data is not a reference type the changes aren't saved. Can anyone help me with this? I'm trying to do something similar to the c# removeLeaves(ref data)

Or is there a way I can remove the leaves in the pack method

```
var pack = data => d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(5)
    (d3.hierarchy(data, d => d.Children)
     //here some kind of filtering
    .sum(d => {            
        return d.Value;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value));
```

Comment: You want to remove Key name ```children```? or if children keyname exists delete object ?

Comment: `if(name == "Children" && !data[name].length){
          delete data[name];
    }`.  like this ?

Comment: Children key always exists so that's why i check if its length is >0 to see if it actually has children. If it doesn't I want to delete this particular object that doesn't have children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose an approach that *recursively/programmatically builds* the desired data structure *instead of mutating* the existing input-data by deleting the not needed properties ...

```js
// {Children: [], Label: "some str", Value: some int, Properties:[] }

const data = {
  Label: "root_with_children",
  Value: 1,
  Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
  Children: [{

    Label: "level_1_without_children",
    Value: 2,
    Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
    Children: []
  }, {
    Label: "level_1_with_children",
    Value: 3,
    Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
    Children: [{

      Label: "level_2_without_children",
      Value: 4,
      Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
      Children: []
    }, {
      Label: "level_2_with_children",
      Value: 5,
      Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
      Children: [{

        Label: "level_3_without_children",
        Value: 6,
        Properties: ["foo", "bar"],
        Children: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

function isNonEmtyArray(type) {
  return (Array.isArray(type) && (type.length >= 1));
}

function collectItemsWithChildrenOnly(list, item) {
  const { Children } = item;
  if (isNonEmtyArray(Children)) {

    const copy = Object.assign({}, item, { Children: [] });
    list.push(copy);

    Children.reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, copy.Children);
  }
  return list;
}

let test;

test = [data].reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, []);
console.log('1st run :: test : ', test);

test = test.reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, []);
console.log('2nd run :: test : ', test);

test = test.reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, []);
console.log('3rd run :: test : ', test);

test = test.reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, []);
console.log('4th run :: test : ', test);

test = test.reduce(collectItemsWithChildrenOnly, []);
console.log('countercheck :: test : ', test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect. I've been trying to change the structure of the data all day yesterday . But I didn't think about creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

asuming you get the array of objects with `Children` property being an array of object or an empty arr indicating it being a leaf you can remove the leaf nodes with combination of following functions

```
const removeEmptyChildren = obj => obj.Children.length
?
    {...obj,Children:leafRemover(obj.Children)}
:
    undefined


const leafRemover = arr => arr.filter( e => removeEmptyChildren(e) !== undefined)
console.log(leafRemover(data)) // where data is array of objects from the server
```

Comment: with this solutin I get "arr.filter is not a function" error. Do you get that as well?

Comment: @GeorgiYakov the data that is being passed to leafRemover function is assumed to be an array so it won't an error, it will be if what ever being received from the server is not an array, as you said..

Comment: @GeorgiYakov if its not an array then pass data.Children to the leafRemover function which is an array..